# MYSQL statement not echoing correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following sql statement..

```
$sql = "select tableid, comment, ID, description from reservations 
        where uniqueid = '" . $reservationid . "'";
```

$reservationid is passed via a POST form. A very similar statement with different fields selected seems to work fine on another page. But when i echo the sql statement on the page i get

```
select tableid, comment, ID, description 
from reservations 
where uniqueid = '51e5f949c1828'
```

It seems to skip the final single quote

I've also tried

```
$sql = "select tableid, comment, ID, description from reservations 
        where uniqueid = '$reservationid'";
```

with the same result. If i view the page source, i can't understand why i see this..

```
select tableid, comment, ID, description from reservations 
where uniqueid = '51e5f949c1828</form
```

where on earth is that stray `</form>`  part coming from?

Comment: can you post sample code

Comment: You should use *prepared statements* after all.

Comment: Post your code. There is no error in sql. You might have not closed double quotes or single quotes somewhere in the form

Comment: try also to use `trim($reservationid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when i echo the sql statement on the page i get
>
> ```
> select tableid, comment, ID, description from reservations where uniqueid = <'51e5f949c1828
> ```

If you "echo" to your browser window, there is great chances that the browser silently removed `</form>` from the display. My *bet* is if you look at the source code of your page while displaying the query, you will see `... where uniqueid = '51e5f949c1828</form>` as well.

As you sure `$reservationid` contain what you expect?

Could you please show some more code. Like your html form? There is probably malformed html and/or unclosed quotes somewhere there.

---

BTW, you should never directly inject a variable from an untrusted source in your query. This leads to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: You are correct! There was a stray tag coming over in the form that the browser removed when i echoed the variable. I am going to take steps to address the sql injection issues.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some error in your form. The data sent is finished incorrectly and therefor a part of the form html is sent with it. Can't really tell without you posting how you send the data.
You will have to correct this to get the code to work.

There's nothing wrong with the PHP you've submitted, however it's an easy target of SQL injection attacks etc. So it's better to go with using for instance sprintf.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf() - it's the better way for this kind of things like combining strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your single and double quotes mixed up.

```
$sql = "select tableid, comment, ID, description from reservations where uniqueid = "' . $reservationid . '"";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do your query like that

```
$sql = "select tableid, comment, ID, description 
       from reservations where uniqueid = '$reservationid'";
```

or simply

```
$sql = "select tableid, comment, ID, description 
        from reservations where uniqueid = $reservationid ";
```